# capybara choose multiple radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I'm running Capybara tests, and I'm stuck on the following test:

```
page.all("input").each do |s|
    if s.value == "E"
        choose(s)
    end
end
click_button "Save answers"
end
```

I have over 500 radio buttons, and each are assigned a value from A-E. I keep getting the error:

```
 Unable to find radio button #<Capybara::Element tag="input" path="[path to element]"> 
 (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Why is it not finding the "input" tag? It should've worked. I've tried `find`, but `find` returns an ambiguous error (500 matches, which is technically what i want).

I want capybara to be able to go through all the input buttons and select those with a value of E.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually found out my problem:

The line `choose(s)` was the line that was giving me the problem. 
`s` is a radio button, and Capybara expected the id of the radio as opposed to the actual radio button itself.

Once I passed in `s[:id]` instead of `s`, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You used radio button wrongly.

Radio button means only one radio is valid. So you can only choose one, instead of several ones with value "E"

If you need multi select, you should use multi checkbox.

Comment: I assume these radio buttons are in different groups.  So field 1 has 5 radio buttons with values from A to E, field 2 has 5 radio buttons, field 3 has 5 radio buttons, etc.   Imagine a multiple-choice test with 100 questions, where each question has 5 answers labeled with an A, B, C, D, or E.

Comment: @iconoclast, maybe you are right but I really can't get that from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
all('input[value=E]').map(&:choose)
```

I don't remember exactly, if that does not work try with click:

```
all('input[value=E]').map(&:click)
```

If that does not work either try with double quotes inside selector:

```
all('input[value="E"]').map(&:click)
```

It should work with `each` too.

But remember what @Billy Chan said.

Comment: See comment for Billy Chan